# Installing RMySQL in Windows 7: "RMySQL was compiled with MySQL 5.5.28 but loading MySQL 6.0.0 instead"

Tags: mysql, r, windows-7, installation, rmysql

I'm trying to install RMySQL on Windows 7 (64 bit), following the instructions at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL.  I'm using R 2.15.1, RTools 2.15, and a full installation of the latest MySQL 5.5.28 and Connector C 6.0.2, and have done the extra step of copying lib and dll files.  When I run install.packages('RMySQL',type='source'), it builds but with the warning:

```
   RMySQL was compiled with MySQL 5.5.28 but loading MySQL 6.0.0 instead!
   This may cause problems with your database connections.

   Please install MySQL 5.5.28.

   If you have already done so, you may need to set your environment
   variable MYSQL_HOME to the proper install directory.
```

This confuses me, as I believe I'm using a consistent and up-to-date installation of MySQL, based on the MySQL Installer (which I have also re-run to check for updates).  My MYSQL_HOME variable is set to "C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLS~1.5/" and so also looks correct.

I'm not sure where the 6.0.0 version number in the warning is coming from.  Based on searches, this appears to be an old 32-bit version of MySQL.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

RMySQL seems to be compiled **not** with the latest version of MySQL that you are using. As the error message says: Install a MySQL version that is compatible with RMySQL.

Comment: Thanks juergen.  However I'm following the standard steps, so can't see why this would be?

Comment: The installation steps did not refer to a specific MySQL version. The package is just not as up-to-date as the MySQL versions that are linked there. The library probably will catch up with the latest MySQL version in a later version.

Comment: So RMySQL isn't up-to-date?  I think purpose of the user using rtools to build it is so that it's not dependent on the SQL version number.

Comment: *This **may** cause problems*: Maybe there won't be problems. You can try using an earlier version of the connector though.